# Why is there no pagebreak in my table?

Tags: tables

Sorry for a stupid question, but I am completely new to Latex. I seem to understand how to create pdf-tables from latex code in TeXworks, but all the tables, which are created, have only 1 page. I am using latex() function from Hmisc package in R to create latex code, which then I use in TeXworks. 
Here is the table I am trying to create:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=7in,noheadfoot,margin=0in]{geometry}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
%latex.default(allfirms_fraction, rowname = NULL)%
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rllllr}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Year}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Zero leverage}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Ultra-low leverage}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Low leverage}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Normal leverage}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Obs}\tabularnewline
\hline
$1950$&32.95\%&9.33\%&11.24\%&46.48\%&$ 525$\tabularnewline
$1951$&23.26\%&9.94\%&10.13\%&56.66\%&$ 533$\tabularnewline
$1952$&19.22\%&8.69\%&10.91\%&61.18\%&$ 541$\tabularnewline
$1953$&20.18\%&8.36\%&9.82\%&61.64\%&$ 550$\tabularnewline
$1954$&23.13\%&6.05\%&10.68\%&60.14\%&$ 562$\tabularnewline
$1955$&22.22\%&7.47\%&10.24\%&60.07\%&$ 576$\tabularnewline
$1956$&19.87\%&7.35\%&11.52\%&61.27\%&$ 599$\tabularnewline
$1957$&17.45\%&7.27\%&11.79\%&63.49\%&$ 619$\tabularnewline
$1958$&16.51\%&8.33\%&11.16\%&63.99\%&$ 636$\tabularnewline
$1959$&17.1\%&8.7\%&11.76\%&62.44\%&$ 655$\tabularnewline
$1960$&16.68\%&8.52\%&11.33\%&63.46\%&$1103$\tabularnewline
$1961$&16.14\%&8.65\%&12.11\%&63.1\%&$1214$\tabularnewline
$1962$&14.29\%&9.95\%&12.01\%&63.75\%&$1407$\tabularnewline
$1963$&14.49\%&9.09\%&11.37\%&65.06\%&$1574$\tabularnewline
$1964$&14.03\%&9.39\%&10.48\%&66.1\%&$1661$\tabularnewline
$1965$&11.74\%&9.01\%&10.07\%&69.19\%&$1798$\tabularnewline
$1966$&10.17\%&7.37\%&8.3\%&74.16\%&$1927$\tabularnewline
$1967$&8.65\%&7.61\%&6.81\%&76.93\%&$2115$\tabularnewline
$1968$&8.08\%&7.71\%&7.3\%&76.91\%&$2672$\tabularnewline
$1969$&6.88\%&6.98\%&7.26\%&78.88\%&$2879$\tabularnewline
$1970$&6.17\%&6.24\%&7.18\%&80.4\%&$3077$\tabularnewline
$1971$&6.19\%&7.32\%&7.85\%&78.65\%&$3185$\tabularnewline
$1972$&6.72\%&7.83\%&7.62\%&77.82\%&$3319$\tabularnewline
$1973$&5.66\%&6.45\%&7.27\%&80.63\%&$3551$\tabularnewline
$1974$&4.88\%&6.01\%&5.62\%&83.49\%&$4427$\tabularnewline
$1975$&5.53\%&7.13\%&6.1\%&81.23\%&$4375$\tabularnewline
$1976$&5.74\%&7.25\%&6.86\%&80.14\%&$4370$\tabularnewline
$1977$&5.36\%&7.15\%&6.46\%&81.04\%&$4351$\tabularnewline
$1978$&4.89\%&6.82\%&6.06\%&82.23\%&$4210$\tabularnewline
$1979$&4.63\%&6.41\%&6.1\%&82.86\%&$4101$\tabularnewline
$1980$&4.79\%&7.18\%&6.74\%&81.29\%&$4111$\tabularnewline
$1981$&5.52\%&7.9\%&8.12\%&78.46\%&$4151$\tabularnewline
$1982$&4.96\%&8.48\%&7.9\%&78.66\%&$4255$\tabularnewline
$1983$&5.75\%&11.58\%&8.4\%&74.28\%&$4455$\tabularnewline
$1984$&5.51\%&10.12\%&8.12\%&76.24\%&$4407$\tabularnewline
$1985$&5.98\%&9.32\%&7.37\%&77.34\%&$4518$\tabularnewline
$1986$&6.38\%&9.51\%&7.87\%&76.24\%&$4688$\tabularnewline
$1987$&6.73\%&9.15\%&7.37\%&76.75\%&$4709$\tabularnewline
$1988$&6.34\%&8.88\%&7.67\%&77.11\%&$4540$\tabularnewline
$1989$&6.89\%&9.16\%&6.98\%&76.97\%&$4456$\tabularnewline
$1990$&7.48\%&9.81\%&6.94\%&75.77\%&$4465$\tabularnewline
$1991$&8.77\%&11.44\%&7.77\%&72.01\%&$4605$\tabularnewline
$1992$&9.45\%&12.73\%&8.21\%&69.61\%&$5018$\tabularnewline
$1993$&10.67\%&13.92\%&8.61\%&66.8\%&$5415$\tabularnewline
$1994$&10.86\%&13.49\%&8.34\%&67.31\%&$5766$\tabularnewline
$1995$&11.35\%&13.96\%&8.19\%&66.5\%&$6424$\tabularnewline
$1996$&12.42\%&15.21\%&8.27\%&64.11\%&$6846$\tabularnewline
$1997$&12.53\%&15.74\%&7.34\%&64.39\%&$6774$\tabularnewline
$1998$&12.83\%&14.22\%&7.08\%&65.87\%&$6807$\tabularnewline
$1999$&12.87\%&15.7\%&7.47\%&63.96\%&$6804$\tabularnewline
$2000$&13.39\%&16.4\%&7.67\%&62.54\%&$6431$\tabularnewline
$2001$&14.06\%&15.21\%&7.55\%&63.17\%&$5811$\tabularnewline
$2002$&15.11\%&14.76\%&6.89\%&63.25\%&$5488$\tabularnewline
$2003$&16.9\%&14.6\%&6.86\%&61.64\%&$5336$\tabularnewline
$2004$&18.34\%&15.32\%&7.39\%&58.95\%&$5235$\tabularnewline
$2005$&19.48\%&15.09\%&7.44\%&57.99\%&$5189$\tabularnewline
$2006$&19.64\%&14.45\%&7.9\%&58\%&$5010$\tabularnewline
$2007$&19.56\%&14.82\%&6.92\%&58.71\%&$4873$\tabularnewline
$2008$&18.57\%&12.86\%&6.84\%&61.73\%&$4675$\tabularnewline
$2009$&18.95\%&14.33\%&7.82\%&58.9\%&$4516$\tabularnewline
$2010$&19.79\%&15.73\%&7.2\%&57.28\%&$4417$\tabularnewline
$2011$&20.13\%&13.8\%&7.32\%&58.75\%&$4356$\tabularnewline
$2012$&19.87\%&12.3\%&7\%&60.83\%&$4383$\tabularnewline
$2013$&20.24\%&11.19\%&7.33\%&61.25\%&$4423$\tabularnewline
$2014$&19.92\%&10.55\%&6.4\%&63.14\%&$4267$\tabularnewline
$2015$&19.68\%&9.9\%&6.58\%&63.84\%&$3465$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}\end{center}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this code in TeXworks, it creates table in 1 page up to year 1990. I tryed opening output pdf-file in different pdf-readers and all shows that there is only single page.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need all these `$ … $` in your table. It can look  nicer with `booktabs` and if you use line breaks in column heads, which can be done with the `\thead` command from `makecell`. So I suggest this layout:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=7in,noheadfoot,margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell,  booktabs}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
{\sisetup{table-format =2.2}
\begin{longtable}{r*{4}{S}r}
\toprule
\thead{Year} & {\thead{Zero\\ leverage}} & {\thead{Ultra-low\\ leverage}} & {\thead{Low\\ leverage}} & {\thead{Normal\\ leverage}} & \thead{Obs}\tabularnewline
\midrule
 & {\%} & {\%} & {\%} & {\%} \tabularnewline
  \endfirsthead
\toprule
\thead{Year} & {\thead{Zero\\ leverage}} & {\thead{Ultra-low\\ leverage}} & {\thead{Low\\ leverage}} & {\thead{Normal\\ leverage}} & \thead{Obs}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\addlinespace[1ex]
 \endhead
 \bottomrule
 \endfoot
 1950 &32.95 & 9.33 & 11.24 & 46.48 & 525 \tabularnewline
 1951 &23.26 &9.94 &10.13 &56.66 & 533 \tabularnewline
 1952 &19.22 &8.69 &10.91 &61.18 & 541 \tabularnewline
 1953 &20.18 &8.36 &9.82 &61.64 & 550 \tabularnewline
 1954 &23.13 &6.05 &10.68 &60.14 & 562 \tabularnewline
 1955 &22.22 &7.47 &10.24 &60.07 & 576 \tabularnewline
 1956 &19.87 &7.35 &11.52 &61.27 & 599 \tabularnewline
 1957 &17.45 &7.27 &11.79 &63.49 & 619 \tabularnewline
 1958 &16.51 &8.33 &11.16 &63.99 & 636 \tabularnewline
 1959 &17.1 &8.7 &11.76 &62.44 & 655 \tabularnewline
 1960 &16.68 &8.52 &11.33 &63.46 & 1103 \tabularnewline
 1961 &16.14 &8.65 &12.11 &63.1 & 1214 \tabularnewline
 1962 &14.29 &9.95 &12.01 &63.75 & 1407 \tabularnewline
 1963 &14.49 &9.09 &11.37 &65.06 & 1574 \tabularnewline
 1964 &14.03 &9.39 &10.48 &66.1 & 1661 \tabularnewline
 1965 &11.74 &9.01 &10.07 &69.19 & 1798 \tabularnewline
 1966 &10.17 &7.37 &8.3 &74.16 & 1927 \tabularnewline
 1967 &8.65 &7.61 &6.81 &76.93 & 2115 \tabularnewline
 1968 &8.08 &7.71 &7.3 &76.91 & 2672 \tabularnewline
 1969 &6.88 &6.98 &7.26 &78.88 & 2879 \tabularnewline
 1970 &6.17 &6.24 &7.18 &80.4 & 3077 \tabularnewline
 1971 &6.19 &7.32 &7.85 &78.65 & 3185 \tabularnewline
 1972 &6.72 &7.83 &7.62 &77.82 & 3319 \tabularnewline
 1973 &5.66 &6.45 &7.27 &80.63 & 3551 \tabularnewline
 1974 &4.88 &6.01 &5.62 &83.49 & 4427 \tabularnewline
 1975 &5.53 &7.13 &6.1 &81.23 & 4375 \tabularnewline
 1976 &5.74 &7.25 &6.86 &80.14 & 4370 \tabularnewline
 1977 &5.36 &7.15 &6.46 &81.04 & 4351 \tabularnewline
 1978 &4.89 &6.82 &6.06 &82.23 & 4210 \tabularnewline
 1979 &4.63 &6.41 &6.1 &82.86 & 4101 \tabularnewline
 1980 &4.79 &7.18 &6.74 &81.29 & 4111 \tabularnewline
 1981 &5.52 &7.9 &8.12 &78.46 & 4151 \tabularnewline
 1982 &4.96 &8.48 &7.9 &78.66 & 4255 \tabularnewline
 1983 &5.75 &11.58 &8.4 &74.28 & 4455 \tabularnewline
 1984 &5.51 &10.12 &8.12 &76.24 & 4407 \tabularnewline
 1985 &5.98 &9.32 &7.37 &77.34 & 4518 \tabularnewline
 1986 &6.38 &9.51 &7.87 &76.24 & 4688 \tabularnewline
 1987 &6.73 &9.15 &7.37 &76.75 & 4709 \tabularnewline
 1988 &6.34 &8.88 &7.67 &77.11 & 4540 \tabularnewline
 1989 &6.89 &9.16 &6.98 &76.97 & 4456 \tabularnewline
 1990 &7.48 &9.81 &6.94 &75.77 & 4465 \tabularnewline
 1991 &8.77 &11.44 &7.77 &72.01 & 4605 \tabularnewline
 1992 &9.45 &12.73 &8.21 &69.61 & 5018 \tabularnewline
 1993 &10.67 &13.92 &8.61 &66.8 & 5415 \tabularnewline
 1994 &10.86 &13.49 &8.34 &67.31 & 5766 \tabularnewline
 1995 &11.35 &13.96 &8.19 &66.5 & 6424 \tabularnewline
 1996 &12.42 &15.21 &8.27 &64.11 & 6846 \tabularnewline
 1997 &12.53 &15.74 &7.34 &64.39 & 6774 \tabularnewline
 1998 &12.83 &14.22 &7.08 &65.87 & 6807 \tabularnewline
 1999 &12.87 &15.7 &7.47 &63.96 & 6804 \tabularnewline
 2000 &13.39 &16.4 &7.67 &62.54 & 6431 \tabularnewline
 2001 &14.06 &15.21 &7.55 &63.17 & 5811 \tabularnewline
 2002 &15.11 &14.76 &6.89 &63.25 & 5488 \tabularnewline
 2003 &16.9 &14.6 &6.86 &61.64 & 5336 \tabularnewline
 2004 &18.34 &15.32 &7.39 &58.95 & 5235 \tabularnewline
 2005 &19.48 &15.09 &7.44 &57.99 & 5189 \tabularnewline
 2006 &19.64 &14.45 &7.9 &58 & 5010 \tabularnewline
 2007 &19.56 &14.82 &6.92 &58.71 & 4873 \tabularnewline
 2008 &18.57 &12.86 &6.84 &61.73 & 4675 \tabularnewline
 2009 &18.95 &14.33 &7.82 &58.9 & 4516 \tabularnewline
 2010 &19.79 &15.73 &7.2 &57.28 & 4417 \tabularnewline
 2011 &20.13 &13.8 &7.32 &58.75 & 4356 \tabularnewline
 2012 &19.87 &12.3 &7 &60.83 & 4383 \tabularnewline
 2013 &20.24 &11.19 &7.33 &61.25 & 4423 \tabularnewline
 2014 &19.92 &10.55 &6.4 &63.14 & 4267 \tabularnewline
 2015 &19.68 &9.9 &6.58 &63.84 & 3465 \tabularnewline
\end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want a page break in your table, use the `longtable` environment.

For the example below I added the `\usepackage{siunitx}` package, which provides the handy column type `S` which helps to align such long list of numbers.

You also might want to have a look at the `booktabs` package, which offers nicer lines and spacing for tables.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=7in,noheadfoot,margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{longtable}{rSSSSr}
\hline\hline
{Year} & {Zero leverage} & {Ultra-low leverage} & {Low leverage} & {Normal leverage} & {Obs}\\
\hline
$1950$&32.95\%&9.33\%&11.24\%&46.48\%&$ 525$\\
$1951$&23.26\%&9.94\%&10.13\%&56.66\%&$ 533$\\
$1952$&19.22\%&8.69\%&10.91\%&61.18\%&$ 541$\\
$1953$&20.18\%&8.36\%&9.82\%&61.64\%&$ 550$\\
$1954$&23.13\%&6.05\%&10.68\%&60.14\%&$ 562$\\
$1955$&22.22\%&7.47\%&10.24\%&60.07\%&$ 576$\\
$1956$&19.87\%&7.35\%&11.52\%&61.27\%&$ 599$\\
$1957$&17.45\%&7.27\%&11.79\%&63.49\%&$ 619$\\
$1958$&16.51\%&8.33\%&11.16\%&63.99\%&$ 636$\\
$1959$&17.1\%&8.7\%&11.76\%&62.44\%&$ 655$\\
$1960$&16.68\%&8.52\%&11.33\%&63.46\%&$1103$\\
$1961$&16.14\%&8.65\%&12.11\%&63.1\%&$1214$\\
$1962$&14.29\%&9.95\%&12.01\%&63.75\%&$1407$\\
$1963$&14.49\%&9.09\%&11.37\%&65.06\%&$1574$\\
$1964$&14.03\%&9.39\%&10.48\%&66.1\%&$1661$\\
$1965$&11.74\%&9.01\%&10.07\%&69.19\%&$1798$\\
$1966$&10.17\%&7.37\%&8.3\%&74.16\%&$1927$\\
$1967$&8.65\%&7.61\%&6.81\%&76.93\%&$2115$\\
$1968$&8.08\%&7.71\%&7.3\%&76.91\%&$2672$\\
$1969$&6.88\%&6.98\%&7.26\%&78.88\%&$2879$\\
$1970$&6.17\%&6.24\%&7.18\%&80.4\%&$3077$\\
$1971$&6.19\%&7.32\%&7.85\%&78.65\%&$3185$\\
$1972$&6.72\%&7.83\%&7.62\%&77.82\%&$3319$\\
$1973$&5.66\%&6.45\%&7.27\%&80.63\%&$3551$\\
$1974$&4.88\%&6.01\%&5.62\%&83.49\%&$4427$\\
$1975$&5.53\%&7.13\%&6.1\%&81.23\%&$4375$\\
$1976$&5.74\%&7.25\%&6.86\%&80.14\%&$4370$\\
$1977$&5.36\%&7.15\%&6.46\%&81.04\%&$4351$\\
$1978$&4.89\%&6.82\%&6.06\%&82.23\%&$4210$\\
$1979$&4.63\%&6.41\%&6.1\%&82.86\%&$4101$\\
$1980$&4.79\%&7.18\%&6.74\%&81.29\%&$4111$\\
$1981$&5.52\%&7.9\%&8.12\%&78.46\%&$4151$\\
$1982$&4.96\%&8.48\%&7.9\%&78.66\%&$4255$\\
$1983$&5.75\%&11.58\%&8.4\%&74.28\%&$4455$\\
$1984$&5.51\%&10.12\%&8.12\%&76.24\%&$4407$\\
$1985$&5.98\%&9.32\%&7.37\%&77.34\%&$4518$\\
$1986$&6.38\%&9.51\%&7.87\%&76.24\%&$4688$\\
$1987$&6.73\%&9.15\%&7.37\%&76.75\%&$4709$\\
$1988$&6.34\%&8.88\%&7.67\%&77.11\%&$4540$\\
$1989$&6.89\%&9.16\%&6.98\%&76.97\%&$4456$\\
$1990$&7.48\%&9.81\%&6.94\%&75.77\%&$4465$\\
$1991$&8.77\%&11.44\%&7.77\%&72.01\%&$4605$\\
$1992$&9.45\%&12.73\%&8.21\%&69.61\%&$5018$\\
$1993$&10.67\%&13.92\%&8.61\%&66.8\%&$5415$\\
$1994$&10.86\%&13.49\%&8.34\%&67.31\%&$5766$\\
$1995$&11.35\%&13.96\%&8.19\%&66.5\%&$6424$\\
$1996$&12.42\%&15.21\%&8.27\%&64.11\%&$6846$\\
$1997$&12.53\%&15.74\%&7.34\%&64.39\%&$6774$\\
$1998$&12.83\%&14.22\%&7.08\%&65.87\%&$6807$\\
$1999$&12.87\%&15.7\%&7.47\%&63.96\%&$6804$\\
$2000$&13.39\%&16.4\%&7.67\%&62.54\%&$6431$\\
$2001$&14.06\%&15.21\%&7.55\%&63.17\%&$5811$\\
$2002$&15.11\%&14.76\%&6.89\%&63.25\%&$5488$\\
$2003$&16.9\%&14.6\%&6.86\%&61.64\%&$5336$\\
$2004$&18.34\%&15.32\%&7.39\%&58.95\%&$5235$\\
$2005$&19.48\%&15.09\%&7.44\%&57.99\%&$5189$\\
$2006$&19.64\%&14.45\%&7.9\%&58\%&$5010$\\
$2007$&19.56\%&14.82\%&6.92\%&58.71\%&$4873$\\
$2008$&18.57\%&12.86\%&6.84\%&61.73\%&$4675$\\
$2009$&18.95\%&14.33\%&7.82\%&58.9\%&$4516$\\
$2010$&19.79\%&15.73\%&7.2\%&57.28\%&$4417$\\
$2011$&20.13\%&13.8\%&7.32\%&58.75\%&$4356$\\
$2012$&19.87\%&12.3\%&7\%&60.83\%&$4383$\\
$2013$&20.24\%&11.19\%&7.33\%&61.25\%&$4423$\\
$2014$&19.92\%&10.55\%&6.4\%&63.14\%&$4267$\\
$2015$&19.68\%&9.9\%&6.58\%&63.84\%&$3465$\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do get rid of all 264 [!] instances of `$` -- they're simply not needed.

Answer (score 5):

This is of course much the same solution as samcarter already provided, but I have a few other suggestions for improvements.

We both use `longtable` to get tables spanning many pages. And we both use `siunitx`. `siunitx`provides some really nice options for formating your numbers in a consistent way.

### Some other suggestions

- You don't usually need to write `\tabularnewline`. Stick to `\\`, unless you insert a `\parbox` or such inside a table.
- Use `booktabs` for some better-looking tables. `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `bottomrule` are lines that are meant to be placed in tables, at positions indicated by their names. Add some breathing room between every few line. `\addlinespace` does this with a predefined, and changeable space.
- Add a `caption` on top. (note, in `longtable`, caption does not work the same way it does in regular tables. It simulates the look, by adding a row. Therefore, it needs `\\` at the end.
- Try not to have too much space between columns, as it might make it difficult to read.
- DRY. Don´t repeat yourself. Here, for instance, you don't need to put `\‰` after every number. This could be added in the definition of the column, with either `siunitx` or `array`. Here, I have omitted them, as I think that repeating the unit for every number is unnecessary, and makes it hinders ease of reading. Possible solutions are to add a row below the header with the unit specified`(%)`, or put it in the caption, as shown in the example.
- Repeat the header and footer on every page. `longtable` handles this nicely. See `\endhead`,`\endfoot`. There are some other great options as well, like `\endfirsthead`. `\endlastfoot`
- Most paperformats are already specified, I would suggest sticking to thos, like `a4paper` or `letterpaper`, unless you have some good reason for specifying lengths yourself.
- Try not to use the `center`-environment. It adds some unwanted vertical space. Use `\centering instead`. `longtable` is centered by default.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=7in,noheadfoot,margin=0in]{geometry}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{longtable}{r*{4}{S}r}
\caption{Some title}\\
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Zero} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Ultra-low} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Low} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Normal}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Year} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{leverage} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{leverage} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{leverage} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{leverage} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Obs}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
1950 & 32.95 & 9.33 & 11.24 & 46.48 &  525\\
1951 & 23.26 & 9.94 & 10.13 & 56.66 &  533\\
1952 & 19.22 & 8.69 & 10.91 & 61.18 &  541\\
1953 & 20.18 & 8.36 & 9.82 & 61.64 &  550\\
1954 & 23.13 & 6.05 & 10.68 & 60.14 &  562\\
\addlinespace
1955 & 22.22 & 7.47 & 10.24 & 60.07 &  576\\
1956 & 19.87 & 7.35 & 11.52 & 61.27 &  599\\
1957 & 17.45 & 7.27 & 11.79 & 63.49 &  619\\
1958 & 16.51 & 8.33 & 11.16 & 63.99 &  636\\
1959 & 17.1 & 8.7 & 11.76 & 62.44 &  655\\
\addlinespace
1960 & 16.68 & 8.52 & 11.33 & 63.46 & 1103\\
1961 & 16.14 & 8.65 & 12.11 & 63.1 & 1214\\
1962 & 14.29 & 9.95 & 12.01 & 63.75 & 1407\\
1963 & 14.49 & 9.09 & 11.37 & 65.06 & 1574\\
1964 & 14.03 & 9.39 & 10.48 & 66.1 & 1661\\
\addlinespace
1965 & 11.74 & 9.01 & 10.07 & 69.19 & 1798\\
1966 & 10.17 & 7.37 & 8.3 & 74.16 & 1927\\
1967 & 8.65 & 7.61 & 6.81 & 76.93 & 2115\\
1968 & 8.08 & 7.71 & 7.3 & 76.91 & 2672\\
1969 & 6.88 & 6.98 & 7.26 & 78.88 & 2879\\
\addlinespace
1970 & 6.17 & 6.24 & 7.18 & 80.4 & 3077\\
1971 & 6.19 & 7.32 & 7.85 & 78.65 & 3185\\
1972 & 6.72 & 7.83 & 7.62 & 77.82 & 3319\\
1973 & 5.66 & 6.45 & 7.27 & 80.63 & 3551\\
1974 & 4.88 & 6.01 & 5.62 & 83.49 & 4427\\
\addlinespace
1975 & 5.53 & 7.13 & 6.1 & 81.23 & 4375\\
1976 & 5.74 & 7.25 & 6.86 & 80.14 & 4370\\
1977 & 5.36 & 7.15 & 6.46 & 81.04 & 4351\\
1978 & 4.89 & 6.82 & 6.06 & 82.23 & 4210\\
1979 & 4.63 & 6.41 & 6.1 & 82.86 & 4101\\
\addlinespace
1980 & 4.79 & 7.18 & 6.74 & 81.29 & 4111\\
1981 & 5.52 & 7.9 & 8.12 & 78.46 & 4151\\
1982 & 4.96 & 8.48 & 7.9 & 78.66 & 4255\\
1983 & 5.75 & 11.58 & 8.4 & 74.28 & 4455\\
1984 & 5.51 & 10.12 & 8.12 & 76.24 & 4407\\
\addlinespace
1985 & 5.98 & 9.32 & 7.37 & 77.34 & 4518\\
1986 & 6.38 & 9.51 & 7.87 & 76.24 & 4688\\
1987 & 6.73 & 9.15 & 7.37 & 76.75 & 4709\\
1988 & 6.34 & 8.88 & 7.67 & 77.11 & 4540\\
1989 & 6.89 & 9.16 & 6.98 & 76.97 & 4456\\
\addlinespace
1990 & 7.48 & 9.81 & 6.94 & 75.77 & 4465\\
1991 & 8.77 & 11.44 & 7.77 & 72.01 & 4605\\
1992 & 9.45 & 12.73 & 8.21 & 69.61 & 5018\\
1993 & 10.67 & 13.92 & 8.61 & 66.8 & 5415\\
1994 & 10.86 & 13.49 & 8.34 & 67.31 & 5766\\
\addlinespace
1995 & 11.35 & 13.96 & 8.19 & 66.5 & 6424\\
1996 & 12.42 & 15.21 & 8.27 & 64.11 & 6846\\
1997 & 12.53 & 15.74 & 7.34 & 64.39 & 6774\\
1998 & 12.83 & 14.22 & 7.08 & 65.87 & 6807\\
1999 & 12.87 & 15.7 & 7.47 & 63.96 & 6804\\
\addlinespace
2000 & 13.39 & 16.4 & 7.67 & 62.54 & 6431\\
2001 & 14.06 & 15.21 & 7.55 & 63.17 & 5811\\
2002 & 15.11 & 14.76 & 6.89 & 63.25 & 5488\\
2003 & 16.9 & 14.6 & 6.86 & 61.64 & 5336\\
2004 & 18.34 & 15.32 & 7.39 & 58.95 & 5235\\
\addlinespace
2005 & 19.48 & 15.09 & 7.44 & 57.99 & 5189\\
2006 & 19.64 & 14.45 & 7.9 & 58 & 5010\\
2007 & 19.56 & 14.82 & 6.92 & 58.71 & 4873\\
2008 & 18.57 & 12.86 & 6.84 & 61.73 & 4675\\
2009 & 18.95 & 14.33 & 7.82 & 58.9 & 4516\\
\addlinespace
2010 & 19.79 & 15.73 & 7.2 & 57.28 & 4417\\
2011 & 20.13 & 13.8 & 7.32 & 58.75 & 4356\\
2012 & 19.87 & 12.3 & 7 & 60.83 & 4383\\
2013 & 20.24 & 11.19 & 7.33 & 61.25 & 4423\\
2014 & 19.92 & 10.55 & 6.4 & 63.14 & 4267\\
\addlinespace
2015 & 19.68 & 9.9 & 6.58 & 63.84 & 3465\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```